# how to determine the number of px scrolled in jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, window

I want to get the value of `px` when I scroll in jQuery.

For example, at the middle of page, I scroll down a little bit. 
Here, I want to know how many `px` I scrolled. (3px, 5px, ..., 10px, 11px ?)

**Whatever the position of the scroller.**

If my scroller is a 300px from the top. I scrolled 10px. So my scroller is now at 310px. How to get the value I scrolled (here : 10px ?)

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working sample code :

```
var startScroll,
    toHandler,
    endScroll;

$(window).on("scroll",function(){
    if (!startScroll) {
        startScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log("Started:" + startScroll);
    } else {
        if (toHandler) {
            clearTimeout(toHandler)
        }
        toHandler = setTimeout(function(){
            endScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            console.log("Ended :"+endScroll);
            console.log("Scrolled "+(endScroll-startScroll));
            startScroll = 0;
        },200)
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Touki/jXwAG/

The timeout is needed to prevent the scroll event to fire multiple times and to get incorrect value.

This sample will print how much pixels it moved after 200ms

Comment: Crazy !!! it works great ! But I have some questions. Why do you use a setTimeout ? And why do you reset `startScroll` to `0` ?

Comment: @Steffi `setTimeout` is to prevent the scroll event to fire multiple times. Without this you would have a "Scrolled: 1px" multiple times, each time the user scrolls down. Resetting the `startScroll` to `0` let the *next* scroll event to re-init the `startScroll`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var distanceScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

**EDIT:**

using a timer (which is in no way accurate) :

```
var timer, lastScrolled = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#test').text('you scrolled '+($(window).scrollTop() - lastScrolled)+' pixels')
        lastScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    },400);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VR5Vz/1/)

Comment: If my scroller is a `300px` from the top. I scrolled `10px`. So my scroller is now at `310px`. How to get the value I scrolled (here : `10px` ?)

Comment: You can't. You can fake it with mousedown, but if the user uses one of the many other ways of scrolling, like mousewheel, it won't work. You could also use a timeout, but how long would you wait? How long does it take to scroll, what if the user scrolls back up again etc.

Comment: Works great ! But why do you use a timer ?